# How to set container state if all required fields are completed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React form with a fair amount of inputs in it (15+ and growing). Currently 3 of the inputs are `required`. I have set up a value in my Redux store of `invalidForm` which by default is set to true. I have a 'Submit' button which checks the state of this `invalidForm` and either disables or enables the button accordingly.

What I would like to do is to set the `invalidForm` value to false when all required inputs have been completed. Ideally the solution would be written so that I can add the `required` attribute to any of the fields in the form and have it still work (there is a similar question on Stack Overflow but it requires manually setting state on all of the required inputs: [How to disable form submit button until all input fields are filled?! ReactJS ES2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978070/how-to-disable-form-submit-button-until-all-input-fields-are-filled-reactjs-es)).

I'm new to React and Redux so still getting my head around some of the concepts. If I were to do this in jQuery I think I would loop through the required inputs, place them into an array with a 'completed' key and when completed set this key to true. Each time one is completed I would test to see if all the items in the array have 'completed' set to true and if so would enable the submit button.

Here is my container

```
class DrillCreator extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DrillCreatorPage
          setDrillTitle={this.props.setDrillTitleAction}
          getDrillTitle={this.props.drillCreator.title}
          setInvalidForm={this.props.invalidFormAction}
          getInvalidForm={this.props.drillCreator.invalidForm}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DrillCreator.propTypes = {
  setDrillTitleAction: PropTypes.func,
  drillCreator: PropTypes.object,
  invalidFormAction: PropTypes.func,
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setDrillTitleAction: drillCreator => dispatch(setDrillTitle(drillCreator)),
  invalidFormAction: drillCreator => dispatch(invalidForm(drillCreator)),
});

const mapStateToProps = reduxState => ({
  drillCreator: reduxState.drillCreator,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DrillCreator);
```

Here is my main page (the 'Submit' button is in the `<EditHeader />` component) and the required props is simply a boolean that is passed down to the relevant input component.

```
const DrillCreatorPage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <EditHeader drillTitle={props.getDrillTitle} invalidForm={props.getInvalidForm} />

      <form>
        <DrillCreationSection>
          <InputWithTooltip
            type="text"
            placeholderText="Title"
            tooltipText="Title Tooltip"
            required
            setDrillTitle={props.setDrillTitle}
          />

          <InputWithTooltip
            type="textarea"
            placeholderText="Summary"
            tooltipText="Summary Tooltip"
          />

          <InputWithTooltip
            type="checkbox"
            options={agesArray}
            placeholderText="Ages"
            tooltipText="Ages Tooltip"
            required
          />

          // etc. etc.
        </DrillCreationSection>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you able to collect if the fields are filled or not?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have said. I already have state set in each <InputWithTooltip /> component which is set to true when the field is filled.

Comment: Then why don't you add `onSubmit` to the form and give form an `id` and your submit button wherever it is, a `form` attribute having the `id` of the form. You can run the `onSubmit` function whenever you click that submit button. Clicking that submit button will trigger onSubmit function of form and you can do whatever you want in the function.

Comment: That won't work as the button is disabled. I want the button to become clickable after the required fields have been filled in.

Comment: Button can be made enabled as you are passing `invalidForm` prop to the component